# Build New XML From Stored XML Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath

We store rather large XML blobs (in an column of `XML` type) and I'm pursuing a skunkworks project to try to build up a subset of the XML on the fly when needed.

Let's say I have this XML blob stored in our database table in a given column:

```
<root>
    <header>
        <id>1</id>
        <name id="foo">Name</name>
    </header>
    <body>
        <items>
            <addItem>
                <val>1</val>
            </addItem>
            <observeItem>
                <val>2</val>
            </observeItem>
        </items>
    </body>
</root>
```

What I want to get out is this is to basically recreate the above document structure but only include one of the `items` children, so for example:

```
<root>
    <header>
        <id>1</id>
        <name id="foo">Name</name>
    </header>
    <body>
        <items>
            <observeItem>
                <val>2</val>
            </observeItem>
        </items>
    </body>
</root>
```

If I were interested in just the `observeItem` record (the `items` element can have any number of children, but I'll only ever be interested in a single one of them).

I know I can do something like `SELECT @XML.query('//items/child::*[2]')` to get just a given child item, but how would I build up the full original document in a query with just one of those children?

Comment: Cant you just delete the <addItem> child from the structure? or do you need it to be more dynamic?

Comment: @MasterYoda needs to be more dynamic, and in practice, I'll be potentially building up this structure for each of the `children`. This whole endeavor is simply to support an edge case where something would fall out of our cache and we'd have to build this "item" specific structure on the fly for reporting purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a solution, but I'm not entirely pleased with it:

```
DECLARE @XML XML = '
    <root>
        <header>
            <id>1</id>
            <name id="foo">Name</name>
        </header>
        <body>
            <items>
                <addItem>
                    <val>1</val>
                </addItem>
                <observeItem>
                    <val>2</val>
                </observeItem>
            </items>
        </body>
    </root>'


DECLARE @NthChild INT = 2

SELECT
    @XML.query('//header'),
    @XML.query('//items/child::*[sql:variable("@NthChild")]') AS 'items'
FOR XML PATH('root')
```

I don't like having to specify the `root` explicitly nor the `items`, but I think this approach could get me by.